# OpenCV 3.0 with OpenCL 2.0, each respond with different versions for OpenCL

Tags: opencv, opencl, amd-gpu

I recently upgraded to a GPU card with OpenCL 2.0 (R9 390), from one with only OpenCL 1.2 on it.  To start using it with OpenCV I created some basic calls to determine what hardware each library thought I had.

```
cout << "Equipment according to OpenCV:" << endl;
    //Setup OpenCV first
cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);

    //OpenCV: Platform Info
std::vector<cv::ocl::PlatformInfo> platforms;
cv::ocl::getPlatfomsInfo(platforms);

    //OpenCV Platforms
for (size_t i = 0; i < platforms.size(); i++)
{
    const cv::ocl::PlatformInfo* platform = &platforms[i];

        //Platform Name
    std::cout << "Platform Name: " << platform->name().c_str() << "\n";

        //Access known device
    cv::ocl::Device current_device;

    for (int j = 0; j < platform->deviceNumber(); j++)
    {
            //Access Device
        platform->getDevice(current_device, j);
        std::cout << "Device Name: " << current_device.name().c_str() << "\n";
    }
}

cv::ocl::Device(current_device); // Required?

cout << cvContext.ndevices() << " GPU devices are detected." << endl; 

for (int i = 0; i < cvContext.ndevices(); i++)
{
    cv::ocl::Device device = cvContext.device(i);
    cout << "name:              " << device.name() << endl;
    cout << "available:         " << device.available() << endl;
    cout << "imageSupport:      " << device.imageSupport() << endl;
    cout << "OpenCL_C_Version:  " << device.OpenCL_C_Version() << endl;
    cout << "Use OpenCL:        " << cv::ocl::useOpenCL() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

cv::ocl::Device(cvContext.device(0)); //Here is where you change which GPU to use (e.g. 0 or 1)

    // Setup OpenCL
cout << "Equipment according to OpenCL:" << endl;
vector<cl::Platform> clPlatforms;
vector<cl::Device> clPlatformDevices, clAllDevices;//, clCTXdevices;
string clPlatform_name, clDevice_name;
cl_uint i;

cl::Platform::get(&clPlatforms);
for(i=0; i<clPlatforms.size();i++)
{
    clPlatform_name = clPlatforms[i].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>();
    cout<< "Platform:         " <<clPlatform_name.c_str()<<endl;
    clPlatforms[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &clPlatformDevices);

        // Create context and access device names
    clContext = cl::Context(clPlatformDevices);
    clCTXdevices = clContext.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

    for(i=0; i<clCTXdevices.size(); i++) {
       clDevice_name = clCTXdevices[i].getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>();
       cout << "Device:       " << clDevice_name.c_str() << endl;
    }
}

cout << "OpenCL Version:    "<<clPlatforms[0].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_VERSION>().c_str() <<endl;
cout << "Vendor:            "<<clPlatforms[0].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR>().c_str() <<endl;
cout << "Extensions:        "<<clPlatforms[0].getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS>().c_str() <<endl;
```

and the output:

```
Equipment according to OpenCV:
Platform Name: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Device Name: Hawaii
Device Name: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q9450  @ 2.66GHz
1 GPU devices are detected.
name:              Hawaii
available:         1
imageSupport:      1
OpenCL_C_Version:  OpenCL C 1.2 
Use OpenCL:        1

Equipment according to OpenCL:
Platform:         AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Device:       Hawaii
Device:       Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q9450  @ 2.66GHz
OpenCL Version:    OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1729.3)
Vendor:            Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Extensions:        cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices
```

So OpenCV thinks I have OpenCL 1.2, while OpenCL is a little smarter and returns 2.0...
Any ideas why they would not return the same version of OpenCL? I'm wondering if I need to re-compile OpenCV so it can recognize that there is a newer version of OpenCL available to it?  Is OpenCV 3.0 limited to using OpenCL 1.2 calls?
Thanks!

Comment: If you statically linked your OpenCV with OpenCL 1.2, yes, you need to recompile.

Comment: I tried that with the following build options: WITH_OPENCLAMDFFT=ON -D WITH_OPENCLAMDBLAS=ON, and the build reports:  --   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                ../opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started completely over and used Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit instead.  Now when I run the same code, the OpenCV library does indeed recognize the GPU as OpenCL 2.0